# Is there an inf constant in Perl?

Tags: perl, infinity

I'm initialising a list with infinities for an algorithm. Writing `$x = 9**9**9` feels unintuitive, and also, I might want to use BigInt in the future. `1/0` throws an error.

What's the canonical way to get `inf`?

Answer (score 20):

You can use the special string `"inf"`:

```
perl -E'say "inf" + 1'
inf
perl -E'say 1 / "inf"'
0
```

et cetera.

Other special strings include `+inf`, `-inf`, `nan`. Of course this also works with `bignum` or `bigint` pragmas. However, these pragmas export equivalent functions `inf` and `NaN` so that you can use barewords.

#### Edit

As @ikegami pointed out, there doesn't seem to be a *portable* way of accomplishing true infinities without a module. I just waded through this [interesting perlmonks thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=858188), but it doesn't get less confusing. Perhaps the best solution would be to accept the performance penalty and `use big{num,int,rat}` from the start, but use `no big{num,int,rat}` in scopes where they aren't required.

Comment: That's not portable. `1` and `Illegal division by zero` for me. It depends on the underlying C library

Comment: big* are just pragma wrappers around Math::Big* functionality; you can use Math::BigInt->binf() if you truly dislike `9**9**9`

Answer (score 3):

I've used [bigrat](https://perldoc.perl.org/bigrat) to do this. It's hard to tell what *features* -E is enabling.

```
use bigrat;
use feature qw(say);

say inf + inf;
say 9**99 / -inf();  #Perl doesn't always like "-inf" by itself
```

`use bigrat;` has been around for a long time, so it should be pretty portable.

Comment: Nice way, however, problems arise if there is floatting function such as cosine in your code, as output will be given as a fraction of two biiig integer, e.g. `cos(3.14159)` would return:

Comment: `-8065817517065989973703096504251912972840411238275937289394319167635251764635679411271282244223719060429803151152349654798328609935270936761090980203083024254269768313969777346198247608509052198790907131451892095265161738806681710725906868653204051476284373642510084894562581651807931406722597475409447496512208699903018331510719` over

Comment: `8065817517094387857166063685640376697528950544088327782400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` :-o !!!