# Perl division by zero - need infinity

Tags: perl

Are there ways to get `inf` or `-inf` from `eval {1/0}`, `eval {1/-0}` instead of `Illegal division by zero` exception?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645034/is-there-an-inf-constant-in-perl.

Comment: @ruakh, I know what it is `inf` in perl, my question is about how to get it from division by zero.

Comment: All I wrote is that that question is related. People finding your question are likely to be interested in that question as well. (Remember, your question is not just for you.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `use bignum`, you'll get `inf` out of `1/0`:

```
use bignum;
print 1 / 0; # produces "inf"
```

`1/-0` is still `inf` (I guess it's because `-0 == 0`).

See http://perldoc.perl.org/bignum.html.

Comment: But `-1/0` returns `-inf`, and it's seems enough for me) Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Out of the box? No, because it's the wrong answer. Division by zero is *undefined* not infinite.

You could use something like `//` to test if the result of your `eval` is undefined:

```
my $result = eval { 1/0 } // 'inf';
print $result;
```

And set a default that way. (Although in the above, `'inf'` is the string; a numeric value might be more useful). There are a selection of maths libraries that give you `inf` type constants, like `bignum` `bigrat` `bigint`. Portability may be an issue though.

Comment: But this way I can't distinguish + and - infinity. As for your note about infinity - it's difficult question: https://www.quora.com/Is-1-0-infinity. I need special numeric value `inf` in my case.

Answer (score 3):

What you really need is [Data::Float](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Float):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Carp qw( croak );
use Data::Float qw( have_infinite pos_infinity neg_infinity float_is_infinite);

have_infinite() or croak "No support for infinite float values";

my $v = -1;
my $x = 1;
my $y = 0;

my $z = eval { $x/$y };
unless (defined $z) {
    $z = ($x >= 0) ? pos_infinity : neg_infinity;
}

print "$z\n";

$z = eval { $v/$y };
unless (defined $z) {
    $z = ($v >= 0) ? pos_infinity : neg_infinity;
}

print "$z\n";
```

Output:

```
$ ./inf.pl
Inf
-Inf
```

Of course, if you are using 5.10 or later, you can do:

```
my $z = eval { $x/$y };
$z //= ($x >= 0) ? pos_infinity : neg_infinity;

print "$z\n";

$z = eval { $v/$y };
$z //= ($v >= 0) ? pos_infinity : neg_infinity;

print "$z\n";
```

Comment: Please, could you provide example how can I use it for division?